# I have found a mistake on someone's code published online: what is the protocol?

Tags: etiquette, code

I have been using an econometrics toolbox for around 2 years and it is great, very useful. It is available from someone's personal website.

I have found a mistake in one piece of code which has set me back for a considerable amount of time. It is a small change but with vast consequences. Instead of questioning the code, I did my idea.

Now that I have found the problem, what is the protocol for highlighting this? Is emailing the author necessary?

Comment: I have edited this to include information from your comments to the answers below. Please edit further if more clarification is necessary or if my edits are inaccurate.

Comment: Is it available on github/bitbucket? If so, just make an issue or even better fork and submit at pull request.

Comment: What is this mistake? I mean: the issue is that the code does not do what the author thinks it does (implementation error) or is the author logic simply wrong for the task they want to solve (semantic error)? In the first case it's generally not a big deal, open an issue in the repository if available or send an email to the mailing list if it exists or just to the author. If it is the second it may be worth a small publication depending on the exact circumstance (if the tool is extensively used by others, whether your solution is a novel idea etc).

Comment: Although it can be rude to point out others' mistakes in general, when it comes to code, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Evorlor How can pointing out mistakes be rude? That's how we learn.

Comment: @user2768 It can be phrased in a rude way, or same people take offence even if it is phrased nicely.

Comment: sub-question: should I inform them anonymously

Comment: @gerrit _It can be phrased in a rude way_, but that seems orthogonal. Also, I agree, _some people take offence_.

Comment: @user30609 Is there any reason to do so anonymously? It seems like it would hinder the process for no advantage.

Comment: @user30609 in case they are offended

Comment: @user30609 I don't think you'll cause offence.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: Write a test demonstrating the bug.  Write a fix that makes the bug go away, as indicated by the test passing.  Submit that.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> Now that I have found the problem what is the protocol for highlighting this, is emailing the author necessary?

It isn't necessary, but **it is the right thing to do**, if you don't, you're responsible for causing others set backs that will waste them a considerable amount of time.

Comment: fair comment, it has been annoying to me, I will think of a nice way to write an email,

Comment: @user30609 Don't overthink this, the email just needs to say something along the lines of: _Dear A, I have been using your econometrics toolbox for around 2 years and it has been very useful for my work. <<Optionally mention some of your work, possibly wrapped in parenthesis.>> Recently I discovered a small mistake in the code: <<describe mistake (and fix if known)>>. Perhaps you can implement this fix and include it in your toolbox; it would save others the frustration of debugging for hours._

Comment: Coders love free fixes to their code.  The two times I notified the coders **and** supplied the fix along with the e-mail, it got deployed within 24 hours.

Comment: @Nelson Coders ... probably. But let's be be honest: There's *lots* of PANTA code in academics (Publish And Never Touch Again). One could play devil's advocate and say: If they were interested in maintaining the code, then they'd put it on a public SCM, and not only offer some ZIP on a personal website. But it's worth a try, of course: The worst thing that can happen is that the message is ignored...

Comment: @Marco13 It could be that they simply don't know about source control. Until very recently, even fresh CS grads seldom knew about it.

Comment: @user2768 Don't call it a mistake; that's rude. *I recently overcame a hurdle in my project by modifying XYZ in your library. I am hoping that you can take a look and determine if this change needs to be applied to your source code or if I've hacked your code in an unsupported way, thank you.*

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've never got this. Why is it rude to point out a mistake, when it's a mistake? Everybody makes mistakes. It's _clearer_ to say it's a mistake that needs fixing, instead of "overcame a hurdle" which would take me a while to parse. Isn't wasting time ruder than bluntness?

Comment: "if you don't, you're responsible for causing others set backs" -- hard agree. Remember you found that one oddity when using OSS and you never reported it? That oddity hurt my productivity, as a result I no longer have my job, and I'm homeless -- thank you a lot for ruining my life, pal. Oh, you did report it? Uhh... where? Why would you report it on some forum that I've never heard of in my life? Are you withholding some information from me specifically? I'm gonna learn ya to take responsibility for your actions. My lawyer will be in contact soon.

Comment: @vaultah That's parabolic. When you're using OSS, you have to not only *anticipate*, but to *assume* that people will mess things up (and the usual disclaimers can be found in the LICENSE.md). The ideal benefits of OSS come into play when everybody plays the game according to the rules, and many academics don't. When the funding is over, they don't give a  .... care about the code, and projecting the responsibilities on others is inappropriate.

Comment: Agreed. The principle is elucidated in [Matthew 18:15-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+18%3A15-17&version=GW), which can be ***VERY*** loosely translated as, *"If your fellow programmer errs, go and show him the mistake, one-on-one. If he fixes the bug, he'll probably be grateful to you, and you'll have made a friend. If he doesn't fix his bug, then ask one or two others who might have more success persuading him to give it a try. If he still won't fix his bug, them go public, and publish the fix on-line."*

It's really just an application of the Golden Rule.

Comment: Of course the OP is not liable for any resulting damages if he does not report this. I think this answer does not mean "responsible" in a "you are to blame" sense, but more "you could have prevented it with minimal effort" - and many people sleep better at night and can lead a happier life, if they know they did the right thing, independent of having to do it or someone else being at fault.

Comment: @Falco No, by _you're **responsible** for causing others set backs_, I really did mean, _you're **to blame** for causing others set backs_. (There's no issue of liability for any wasted time.) I believe the OP has a responsibility to act.

Comment: @user2768 I don't think I can agree with this. I would not blame someone for not going out of their way to possibly help strangers, where he doesn't even know if they want or need help and if the author actually cares. I think it is a nice thing to do and would also do it myself, but I would never blame someone for not doing it - I don't see it as a duty which needs to be done, but rather a good act which one might do if he wants to do something nice.

Comment: @Falco I see it as a duty. (It's worth noting that the OP is not _going out of their way to possibly help strangers_, they merely need to send a single email.)

Comment: @user2768 we're delving into morals/philosophical here. But there are probably a million little things (as small as sending an email) you could do every day, which would make other peoples lives better. If all of them were a duty, you'd have no time at all for yourself.

Comment: @Falco I'm merely identifying what I consider to be a researcher's duty. I don't consider the _million little things_ to which you elude as part of a researcher's duty. You could write you own answer, given that you disagree.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because you just write "it is the right thing to do" which is also my opinion. Only in the comments do you go explicit that you see it as a duty which is compelling to every researcher. The difference is just, I agree one is a better human if one does this, but not a worse if one does not.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are papers out there deliberately filled with errors with the explicit intention of wasting researchers' time, particularly the time of those researchers effective and conscientious enough to notice and take the time to point out these errors.

Answer (score 53):

An important point of etiquette that has been skipped in the other answers:

Treat it as a *suspected* bug, and do not assume "I'm right, you're wrong" while presenting your fix.

- No matter how confident you are on the matter, there is *always* room for having misinterpreted or overlooked something important.

Consider the case of finding an 'error' in code of:

```
(A + B)
```

And you decide that all of *your* use cases need this to be:

```
ABS(A + B)
```

Your use cases may not include a need for that possible negative to exist, or even be able to handle it when it does, but that does not mean cases outside of your consideration may not require them.

- Start off with the assumption that the original coders know more about the code than you do. [They might not actually, but opinions of others can always be re-evaluated...]
- Approach it as having a goal of mutually gaining a better understanding of what the code is doing, and what it should be doing, and how it is actually being used.
- Consider phrasing any suggestions for changes/improvements as *questions* rather than *commands*. ["Do you see any flaws in my attempt at fixing my problem?" vs "You should use my code instead."]

Comment: Totally agree!!

Comment: The OP writes, _I have found a mistake in one piece of code_, so this doesn't really answer the question, it questions the legitimacy of the question and answers a different one.

Comment: @user2768 - They _Think_ they have found a mistake, and they probably have, and they asked for a protocol on how best to handle it. Part of the proper protocol is to leave the door wide open to the possibility that you are in fact wrong about the nature of the mistake you've found... If you think this answers 'a different question', then you've entirely missed the point of the answer.

Comment: @TheLuckless You think the OP _thinks_, but they might _really know_ there's a mistake. This isn't impossible, I've done it myself on numerous occasions. I've also thought there wasn't a mistake and I follow your advice when I'm in doubt.

Comment: @user2768 no matter how much one 'really knows' about a software bug, _proper etiquette_ is to _still assume you might be wrong, no matter how sure you are that you're right_. It is the polite standing to start out such a conversation on, and covers your backside if you do actually overlook something. - Also don't forget that it is also entirely possible for BOTH parties to be wrong. Bugs in code and design aren't exactly uncommon...

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to worry about who is right and who is wrong.  Maybe they are both right.  Maybe they are both wrong.  It does not matter.

Comment: @TheLuckless There are cases when I think that's just wrong, e.g., the first three digits of pi being defined as  3.13. In such cases, there's really no point in _assuming you might be wrong_, clearly approximating pi as 3.13 is wrong.

Comment: @emory: Humans are not robots. We are *far* more willing to listen to "Can you help me understand X?" instead of "X is why you are wrong." It's a matter of tact, nothing more.

Comment: @Kevin Suppose I write some software based on Freedom Units.  I can acknowledge that the software would be more generally useful if written in Metric Units without agreeing to a change.  I only care about my utility.  This is the beauty of open source software.  If you want, you can fork it to Metric Units without my permission.

Answer (score 7):

You have 3 possibilities:

1. Contact the author as per the other answer. Best option based on the subsequent comments revealing that the source was a personal website.

If the code was published in an article or paper then the following may be applicable:

2. Contact the editor.
3. Publish a paper showing your work to improve the usefulness of the code.

The third depends on the type of error and how it was corrected - if it meant changing a 3 to 5 then that is trivial, but if it meant re-coding a significant portion with an extra process then it may well be a suitable option.

You have to tell somehow though.

Comment: I'll just add that if the code is on some online repository (e.g. GitHub) then there's a standard way of doing this.

Comment: It was a small change with vast consequences, I don't think it would warrant a paper, nor would I like to profit off of somebodies misfortunes.

Comment: It is on a personal website

Comment: Then it is clear you have made your decision - just say that it was so useful for you and you found the error...

Comment: (2) doesn't seem relevant from the original question, nor the OP's comment. (3) doesn't seem appropriate without further information: Writing a paper on a software bug seems rather unusual. I suppose (2) is relevant if the software's code were published in an article, since the editor may publish a note on the bug. Similarly, I suppose (3) is relevant if the software's code were published in an article. Perhaps @SolarMike had different scenarios in mind.

Comment: @user2768 I had assumed (incorrectly as it turns out) the the OP had got the code from a published paper of some sort. Now it has become clear that it was copied from a personal website that changes the game. Oh, if only all questions were written perfectly so that answers could focus on the correct direction...

Comment: @SolarMike assumption is the mother of all **** up's

Comment: @user30609 writing a clear question is useful on here, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry @SolarMike I meant on my behalf, I should have written the question clearly and not assumed that the potential readers knew what I was saying

Answer (score 6):

If you are the programmer yourself, and this is the open source project, best would be just to submit the pull request if they have the SCM repository. Both software would be fixed and you would get credits.

If not, report the bug, best over they bug database if they have any. Blogging about the issue on some random place makes little sense because it may take forever for the authors to find your comments.

If this is some obsolete team that has no repository and no bug database, may make sense to take over the project.

Answer (score 4):

Many repositories have a file "CONTRIBUTING.md". The file contains guidelines for providing feedback, bug reports or how you open pull requests. ([Example 1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) , [example 2](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md))
Other projects have a web page or wiki with a "How to Contribute" section, where you can find this information.

If you don't find any of this, you should write an email with the bug report and ask the repository owner on the following procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point that people are publishing code exactly because they want/expect some bugfixes/improvements. I've sent some fixes in my life (or just reported issues), and they were mostly well received. Even when I was wrong (turned out that compilers have the freedom to interpret "undefined behaviour" in the most liberal way).

So don't be afraid to send a report/patch!